# NAudio - Cannot pass a GCHandle across AppDomains

Tags: handle, naudio

A client of mine has a long-running process that uses NAudio to record incoming audio on the default recording device for a few hours on a scheduled basis. It runs as a desktop program that is left running for days or weeks at a time.

Today he sent me this exception report:

```
Cannot pass a GCHandle across AppDomains.
Parameter name: handle
System.ArgumentException
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.InternalCheckDomain(IntPtr handle)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.FromIntPtr(IntPtr value)
   at NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.Callback(IntPtr waveInHandle, WaveMessage message, IntPtr userData, WaveHeader waveHeader, IntPtr reserved) in C:\Libraries\NAudio\naudio-5019c8f1c6fc\NAudio\Wave\WaveInputs\WaveIn.cs:line 132
   at NAudio.Wave.WaveWindow.WndProc(Message& m) in C:\Libraries\NAudio\naudio-5019c8f1c6fc\NAudio\Wave\MmeInterop\WaveWindow.cs:line 64
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I did some googling but couldn't find anything obvious. Is there a good patch or fix for this that doesn't involve silently catching the exception?

I'm using a home-built version of NAudio that includes a few tweaks, but nothing that should cause this error.

Comment: very strange. You could try using WaveInEvent instead. Alternatively try recreating WaveIn every time you need to record.